# "Hit up" or "go to"

Tags: word-usage

What sounds more natural:

> I don't want to go to the Museum,why don't we **hit up** the souvenir shops instead?
>
> I don't want to go to the Museum,why don't we **go to** the souvenir shops instead?

What sounds better **go to** or **hit up**?

Maybe "go to" sounds better.(atleast that's what I guess.)

Comment: "hit up" us slang. See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+up.

Answer (score 1):

"To hit up" is informal and should be used with persons. You can hit up somebody, not something.

See [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hit-up-someone):

> **hit up someone** (informal) (phrasal verb) = ​to ask someone for something, esp. money:
>
> - She tried to hit me up for a loan till payday, but I didn’t have any money to give her.

So **go to** is better.

Also, I would use a **full stop** instead of a **comma**, to split the sentences.